# Connect Web Service written in Guest OS of VMware from Host OS

Tags: virtual-machine, web

**Guest**: Open SuSE 11.4

My Web Service, written in Web Services in Java in VMware Workstation 6.5, is in Guest OS.

**Host**: Windows 7

Tomcat project

As a beginner, how do I publish VM Web Services (in UDDI or in client project) in Host OS? Do I need static IP address setting and are configuration changes needed?